# How to correctly use suspend fun in Retrofit 2.6.0 coroutines with kotlin

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines, suspend, retrofit2.6

I'm trying to write my network request to use Retrofit 2.6.0 and coroutines suspend fun. But i keep getting null object. This is the first time am trying retrofit 2.6 and coroutines

here is my sample code

Data class

```
data class ProjectList (val data: List<Project>)
```

Sample JSON Object

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "project_id": "10824",
            "project_name": "Bendor Project",
            "project_number": "P010824",
            "content_items": [
                {
                    "content_id": "235",
                    "content_name": "Longonot Project",
                    "content_description": "Valves Example ",
                    "content_date_updated": "2019-08-31 12:29:00",
                    "project_id": "10824",
                    "media_items": []
```

Network Interface

```
    suspend fun getProjects(@Query("mode") mode: String): ProjectList
```

Retrofit Client

```
class RetrofitClient{


    private val gson = GsonBuilder()
        .setLenient()
        .create()


    private fun retrofit(): Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build()

    val retrofitService: ProjectAPI by lazy {
        retrofit().create(ProjectAPI::class.java)
    }
```

Repository

```
class ProjectRepository {

    private val client: ProjectAPI = RetrofitClient().retrofitService

    suspend fun getProjectData(mode : String) : ProjectList = client.getProjects(mode)

}
```

livedata in ViewModel

```
val request : LiveData<ProjectList> = liveData(Dispatchers.IO){
            val response = repository.getProjectData(SOURCE_MODE)
            Log.e(TAG, "${response.data}")
            emit(response)
        }
```

I keep getting null response. Where am i not getting it right?

Comment: Looks like you are doing everything correctly. Can you change the type to `Response<ProjectList>` and debug the request to see if the request matches what you are intended to send?

Comment: I just replaced this

```val request : LiveData<ProjectList> = liveData(Dispatchers.IO){
            val response = repository.getProjectData(SOURCE_MODE)
            Log.e(TAG, "${response.data}")
            emit(response)
        }```

TO 
```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            val response = repository.getProjectData("main")
            Log.e(TAG, "${response.data}")
            liveProjectData.postValue(response.data)
        }```

Trying to figure out the diffrence

Comment: share Project class first

Comment: u're probably doing something wrong while parsing

Comment: my another view is u don't need to emit values, just call suspend func. and then create LiveData in your ViewModel and last call livedata.post() in order to be able to assign network response to your LiveData

Comment: @ZaferCelaloglu I had it working already with similar idea of your last comment. Thanks

Comment: then let me convert my comments to answers, please approve it :)

Comment: @ZaferCelaloglu sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need to emit values, just call your `suspend func` in coroutine scope and then create a new `LiveData` in your `ViewModel` and lastly call liveData.post() in order to be able to assign the response of network request to your `LiveData` object.